# Kotlin: Higher-order function with Suspend Function return type

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

How to return suspend function from regular function? How to create suspend function instance?

For example, I can return async result from function:

```
fun <T> f(g: () -> T): Deferred<T> = GlobalScope.async { g() }
```

But I notices Kotlin allow the following signature of function:

```
fun <T> f(g: () -> T): suspend () -> T {
    TODO()
}
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rene's answer but shorter:

```
fun <T> f(g: () -> T) = suspend { g() }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
fun <T> f(g: () -> T): suspend () -> T {
    suspend fun intern() = g()
    return ::intern
}
```